# Locating and filling with a corresponding value using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to locate a null value in a corresponding column and fill it with an existing corresponding value.

Eg:

```
a 1
b 3
b null
d null
d 4
```

so I want to fill the null for b with 3 and d with 4.

The code I tried is as follows:

```
for x in df['Item_Identifier'].unique():

    if df.loc[df['Item_Identifier' == x,'Item_Weight']].isnull:
        
df.loc[df['Item_Identifier','Item_Weight']].fill(df.loc[df['Item_Identifier','Item_Weight']] is not 'null')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! This does not seem to be a well defined question yet. The filling value is not unique and you do not specify how you want to resolve the ambiguity. Hint: if you would define it, you would be able to formulate a much more better targeted question that aims directly at the thing you are missing to solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you @DmitriChubarov. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: The solution you've prescribed gives an error: ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)
How will it know that it needs to act on Col2?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to fill the missing values per group with the nearest value.

You can `groupby`+`ffill`/`bfill`:

```
(df.replace({'null': float('nan')})
   .groupby(df['col1']).ffill()
   .groupby(df['col1']).bfill()
   .convert_dtypes()
)
```

output:

```
  col1  col2
0    a     1
1    b     3
2    b     3
3    d     4
4    d     4
```

used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a', 'b', 'b', 'd', 'd'],
                   'col2': [1, 3, 'null', 'null', 4]})
```

Comment: Hi Mozway,  Thankyou for the answer. I'm trying to locate a value in a column of a dataframe and fill in the value in the corresponding column with a value above or below it.
The solution you've prescribed wouldn't know of the corresponding column.

Comment: @Amit do you mean you want to restrict the fill to given columns? It's easy, you just need to slice them and assign. Can you update your question to provide an example?

Comment: I couldn't find the option to update the original question so I'm posting here..

The DataFrame is like:

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd'],
                   'col2': ['x', 'y', 'z', 'w', 'v', 'x', 'y', 'z'],
                   'col3': [3.2, 1.1, 'Null', 1.1, 2.6, 3.4, 'Null', 3.4]})


Now I need to find the null values in col3. Find the corresponding cell in Col1. Find the value in col3 for the group the cell belongs to in col1. Fill the empty cell in col3 with that value.

Comment: @AmitBhise this seems to work with the provided code (of course you need to change the `null` into `Null`), maybe provide the expected output. If you want to edit your question, click on the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70003529/edit) link below it

Comment: But how would it know which column to act on. We're not mentioning it in the code.
It gives: ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)

Comment: @AmitBhise please provide an example for which it doesn't work and I'll update my question

Comment: It's the BigMart3 dataset. It's popular and freely available.

I'm trying to input the Item_Weight using the Item_Identifier.

Comment: Well sorry, but it's not my burden to go find the data to help you ;)

Comment: ofcourse it isn't @mozway.. my bad.. :-)
It's like the below:
 df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'd', 'c', 'd'], 'col2': ['x', 'y', 'z', 'w', 'v', 'x', 'y', 'z'], 'col3': [3.2, 1.1, 2.6, 'Null',  3.4, 'Null', 1.1, 3.4]})
Now I need to groupby on col1 and fill values in col3.. the code you prescribed doesn't mention col3.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```py
df.groupby(col1)[col3].ffill().bfill()
```

Comment: Hey friends,
This is the wrong answer. What I tried is:
df.groupby('col1')['col2'].get_group('b').fillna('value', inplace = True)

Both, replace() and fillna() are not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at the `limit` parameter of `bfill` and `ffill`:

```
df['col2'].replace('null', np.nan).ffill(limit=1).bfill(limit=1)
```

Output:

```
0    1.0
1    3.0
2    3.0
3    4.0
4    4.0
Name: col2, dtype: float64
```

Comment: That is close @Scott Boston but we need to get the value from that column first. I'm trying to edit the question.